# Position right without float

Tags: css, html

Hi guys (and gals) I'm just trying to align a form to the right of my navbar, right now I'm using a float, but the problem is once the window size becomes too small for it all to fit on one line, it jumps outside the navbar, instead of the navbar following with it, so my question is:

How can I align to the right, without float or absolute positioning. This is my code right now:

```
.navbar .form {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 43px;
}
```

Also the padding on my `hero-body` class causes the right side of the border to push out past the container, how can I fix that?

```
.hero-body {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF 0, #FFFFFF 85%, #EEEEEE 100%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #ccc;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HlhEj
[image]

Comment: why are you opposed to absolute positioning? if you make your bar `position:relative` then you can position the form absolutely within the relatively-positioned container (`right:0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by applying a clearfix on the `.navbar`.

**Add this**

```
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
```

**Add the `.clearfix` class:**

```
<div class="navbar clearfix">
```

The navbar will now expand vertically to compensate for the lack of horizontal space.

Comment: Thanks for this, but how does it work? Also any idea why my padding is pushing the right side of hero-body out?